# Enable all checkboxes with one checkbox click with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, html-table

I have a table where I have a column name and near the column name I have a checkbox. That particular column name values inside the table by default are check boxes. What I need is that when I enable the checkbox near the column name, all the checkboxes in the table under that column should be enabled and when I disable the checkbox in column name all checkboxes in table under the column should also be disabled?

```
<div class="Container">

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="table_header">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Old date</th>
          <th>New date</th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> Status
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let form of formlist; index as i">
          <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
          <td>{{form.cat }}</td>
          <td>{{form.olddate }}</td>
          <td>{{ form.newdate }}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is that when I enable the checkbox near the column name status, all the checkboxes in the table under that column should be enabled and when I disable the checkbox in column name all checkboxes in table under the column should also be disabled?

Comment: are you using FormArray? Try to provide a stackblitz example

Comment: And you're doing it wrong. ID should be unique in a page. You should not use vehicle1 id for multiple elements

Comment: Please show your component code. You'll have to write code in your component so we have to understand how is built the `formlist` array.

Comment: You can simple write a onclick function. no need of comp ts code. I am not using form array

Answer (score -1):

You can give class to checkbox and with jQuery you can check enable or disable:

```
.attr("disabled",true)
.attr("disabled",false)
```

Comment: I work in angular. can u pls write the code for that?

Answer (score -1):

remove "vehicle1" id from `<td>` elements, then copy and paste script given below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){

 $("#vehicle1").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

});
</script>
```

**In Angular**

```
<label class="btn btn-filter">
  <input type="checkbox" name="allTrades" [value]="trade" (change)="allTrades($event)">All Trades
</label>&nbsp;
<ng-container *ngFor="let trd of trade">
  <label class="btn btn-filter">
    <input type="checkbox" name="trades" [checked]="trd.selected" (change)="changeTradesByCategory($event)">{{ trd.label }}
  </label>&nbsp;
</ng-container>

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

 trade = [
    { label: 'aa', selected: false }, 
    { label: 'bb', selected: false }, 
    { label: 'cc', selected: false }, 
    { label: 'dd', selected: false }
  ];

allTrades(event) {
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    this.trade.forEach(item => item.selected = checked);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u say the same for angular

Comment: I tried this but I want the values in the table without label. Like only the checkbox. In this code it comes with the value of lable in trade list. If I remove that list or enter emplty lable the checkbox is not coming

Comment: @ExpertLabs just remove `{{ trd.label }}` from the HTML...

Comment: I have tried that but it showed empty values in checkboxes